# How to apply background color with css to text with line break

Tags: html, css

I've put it in a jsfiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/og90214y/

I need to set so the background follows the text and not `<p>` elements width. For that I've set `display: inline`.

For padding to both sides I've got `box-shadow: 45px 0 0 #f00,-45px 0 0 #f00;`, but this padding doesn't work on `FireFox` (works on `Chrome`), on FireFox it only works for the first line and for the rest there is padding, but without background color on it.

What could I do to make it work on FireFox as well and show padding + background color on those 45px at each end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this property `box-decoration-break: clone;` & remove `box-shadow`

```
.slider-text p {
background: #f00 none repeat scroll 0 0;
box-decoration-break: clone;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
color: #fff;
display: inline;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.4;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/og90214y/6/

Answer (score 0):

use display:inline-block and it will work. The background oclour will fill the text space and not just the paragraph

Comment: And how can I give margin to lines with this?