# apply background-color only for text

Tags: html, css

I want to highlight only the  text  and need to aligh the text in center and need to align the button to float in center.I tried `margin-left:auto;margin-auto;` but not working for input tag

```css
.banner-heading{
  background-color: #99408c;
  font: 31px  roboto thin;
  color:#fff;  
  width:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.banner-content{
  background-color: #99408c;
  font: 50px  roboto thin;
  color:#fff; width:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.order {
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffa200), color-stop(1, #ffa200));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200', endColorstr='#ffa200',GradientType=0);
  background-color:#ffa200;
  border:1px solid #ffa200;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:30px;
  padding:9px 70px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffa200;
  margin-left:35%;
  margin-right:35%;
}
.order:hover {
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffa200), color-stop(1, #ffa200));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200', endColorstr='#ffa200',GradientType=0);
  background-color:#ffa200;
}
.order:active {
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row banner">
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <p class="banner-heading">ORDER ONLINE AND ENJOY HOMELY FOOD IN JUST</p>
         <P class="banner-content">3 SIMPLE STEPS</P>
         <p class="banner-button">
             <form method="post">
                 <input type="submit" name="register" value="LET ME ORDER" class="order"> 
             </form>
         </p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719894/how-to-apply-background-color-with-css-to-text-with-line-break/34721006#34721006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.banner-heading{
 
 font: 31px  roboto thin;
    color:#fff;  
 width:auto;
 text-align:center;
 
}
.banner-content{
 
 font: 50px  roboto thin;
    color:#fff; width:auto;
 
 text-align:center;
}

.order {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffa200), color-stop(1, #ffa200));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200', endColorstr='#ffa200',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#ffa200;
 border:1px solid #ffa200;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:30px;
 padding:9px 70px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffa200;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
.order:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffa200), color-stop(1, #ffa200));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200', endColorstr='#ffa200',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#ffa200;
}
.order:active {

 top:1px;
}
   
.sbt_btn{
    text-align:center;
    
}
```

```html
 <div class="row banner">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p class="banner-heading"><span style="background-color: #99408c">ORDER ONLINE AND ENJOY HOMELY FOOD IN JUST</span></p>
   <P class="banner-content"><span style="background-color: #99408c">3 SIMPLE STEPS</span></P>
   <form method="post">
      <div class="sbt_btn">
      <input type="submit" name="register" value="LET ME ORDER" class="order">
            </div>
    
    </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, i hope this can help for you.

```css
.banner-heading {
  background-color: #99408c;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  font: 24px roboto thin;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
.banner-content {
  background-color: #99408c;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  font: 50px roboto thin;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
.row.banner {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.order {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffa200;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffa200), color-stop(1, #ffa200));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200', endColorstr='#ffa200',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#ffa200;
 border:1px solid #ffa200;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:30px;
 padding:9px 70px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffa200;
 margin-left:35%;
 margin-right:35%;
}
.order:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffa200), color-stop(1, #ffa200));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffa200 5%, #ffa200 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200', endColorstr='#ffa200',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#ffa200;
}
.order:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row banner">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <p class="banner-heading">ORDER ONLINE AND ENJOY HOMELY FOOD IN JUST</p>
   <P class="banner-content">3 SIMPLE STEPS</P>
   <p class="banner-button"> <form method="post">
    
      <input type="submit" name="register" value="LET ME ORDER" class="order">
    
    </form></p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Divs have `display: block;` by default and `block` elements stretch the whole width of the page. To highlight only *text*, set `display:inline-block;` for `banner-heading` and `banner-content`.

Now to use `margin: auto;`, the element should be provided a specific width. So set width for `order`, `banner-heading` and `banner-content`.

**Note:** `width: 100%;` won't work because there ain't going to be any space left after that. So always try to give only as much width as necessary.